# Looking for a Image Chooser in Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to be able to browse the image from my web directory, select one of them or more and manipulate them. Like Store them... copy them.... resize them etc.

Any plugins or Code to make this possible?

Comment: It's generally considered the least one can do to respond to answerers so they can improve their answers enough for someone to earn "Best Answer" status. Mind participating?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the closest pre-built thing I know of is a file manager called [Mollify](http://www.mollify.org/index.php), but it can't edit images. (Note: I generally only know about open-source things)

However, you could build you own using some mixture of these resources:

- [Image Uploads with 100% Less Suck. Guaranteed.](http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload) (AJAX image upload with preview)
- [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php) (Polished, desktop-like cropping widget)
- [iPhoto-like Image Resizing Using Javascript](http://www.agilepartners.com/blog/2005/12/07/iphoto-image-resizing-using-javascript/) (Can be adapted for intuitive resizing control. Just read off the width and height on submit and use PHP to do the manipulation)
- [PHP GD](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)
- [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) (Has BMP-reading code to supplement GD that you may want to borrow)
- [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) (Object-oriented image manipulation library for PHP which uses GD for the heavy work. Also has BMP read/write code, but it's experimental.)
- [PaintbrushJS](http://github.com/mezzoblue/PaintbrushJS) (Pure JS image-manipulation library. If you decide to implement more complex operations, this could be used to preview them.)

Sorry I can't be more helpful.